# How can I keep my ongoing audio task ongoing?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I'm having a specific problem that I'd love some insight on. Here is my code

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setDataAndType(media, mediaType);
startActivity(i);
```

This starts an audio activity for me and it even puts a notification item in the notification bar saying that it is an ongoing task. However, if I hit the Home button or Back button the ongoing task is immediately killed for me. I was confused by this behavior.

I found a way to keep the task going by the following: when the audio activity starts I drag down the notification bar and click the notification item ( which really just shows me the same activity again ) and when I do this it behaves accordingly. When I click the Home button it continues. When I hit the back button, it continues. For some reason when I click the notification item the "correct" Intent is fired.

What I'd like is for this behavior to start when I first launch the audio, because no one that uses my app is going to pull down the notification bar and click the notification item to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Service`. Specifically, you will want to call `startForegroundService()` in the service's creation/start callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a service already available for this feature ( playing audio )? I would think there would be but I haven't been able to find one. I do know how to create my own, but that seems like I'd have to reinvent the wheel a bit, because I don't just want to be able to play background music, but I also want the UI controls for the music as well ( I.E. seek bar, previous, next, play, pause ).

Comment: take a look at http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java;h=9b1fd58fe1fe10bcc46cdda28fcc9772d8e16da4;hb=refs/heads/master

This is from the music player included with vanilla android.

Comment: that's a good source, I've seen it before, I was just wondering if they're be a way to use it with startService(), but it's looking more and more like I'll just have to write my own service.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to write your own, because there is no guarantee that someone will have this service on their device (if you can even use it)

Comment: Alright good to get some closure on this, thanks. Writing the Service code won't be too hard.